# Fixing Ugly boxplot in R by better representing data

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I make my boxplot nicer? Most of the data is clumped up together on one side of the plot. Also in my Rmd display it is cut off. What can I do to make this nicer looking and a better representation of my data?

Code:

```
boxplot(df2$Runtime[df2$drama == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$comedy == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$short == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$romance == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$action == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$crime == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$thriller == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$documentary == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$adventure == 1], 
df2$Runtime[df2$animation == 1], 
names = names(top10),
horizontal = TRUE, yaxt="n")

axis(2, labels = names(top10), at=1:length(top10), las=2)
```

Each genre is in a dataframe with values of 0 or 1. Runtime has a integer value representing minutes

sample data:

```
> head(df2$Runtime); head(df2$drama); head(df2$comedy)
[1]  70  21 106  75  14  82
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Result
[image]

Comment: without any data, it us hard for us to do much.

Comment: @G5W Updated. I am pretty new to R so this is a bit difficult for me to represent the problem/data in a meaningful way. Would appreciate a bit of guidance and specifics. Thank you

Comment: Clearly your runtime distributions are quite right-skewed. Have you tried plotting the log-transformed runtimes? Or you could Z-transform all runtimes, and then plot individual distributions in units of standard deviations?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have no idea how to implement that

Comment: @Liondancer Concerning the log-transformation, instead of `boxplot(df2$Runtime[df2$drama == 1], ...` do `boxplot(log10(df2$Runtime[df2$drama == 1]), ...`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers it does look nicer. The graph is exaggerated quite a bit. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @Liondancer; perhaps showing [violin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot) or [ridgeline](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/07/joyplots.html) plots instead of box plots might be a better choice for visualising your (log-transformed) data. There are some nice R packages around that might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say too much without having the data to play around with. It's admittedly hard when your problem is that the data is really dense in some areas. But you could provide just a small amount of data with maybe a few categories. People usually use `dput` to output results and copy and paste it here. If it's copied and pasted as a table it's easy enough to read into R :)

As for your question, data visualisation is always tricky! You're getting lots of dots because they're outliers, i.e. are outside a certain number of SDs given your sample size. So parts of your data are just really dense. So maybe rather than a boxplot, you could try something like a violin plot?

In R there's an amazing package called `ggplot2`. The more time you spend trying to plot things in R, the closer you'll get to using this until you make the jump.

I'll make a guess that you can do something like the below with your data. If this isn't working (not 100% sure what the structure of your data is) check out [this page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html) which might give you a better idea on how to use it.

The other caveat, is I am assumming there is a `Genre` column which says what the genre is. If this does not yet exist, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421967/r-converting-multiple-binary-columns-into-one-factor-variable-whose-factors-are) which shows how to convert several binary columns to one column with factor labels.

If you're in a scenario where some films can have multiple genres, you'll want to replicate data for the below solution to work. I.e. if you have a movie that is both comedy and short, then it should appear twice (i.e. in a row twice) with the genre different in each entry.

With all that said, onto the simple solution!

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Genre, y = Runtime)) + geom_violin()
```

That's it once you've got it set up. The trick is getting used to `ggplot2` and the types of inputs it wants. Remember you'll need to install the ggplot2 library for this to work.

If data still looks a little weird, Maurits Evers' solution to transform data is a good one too. In fact, i think this with a ggplot2 approach would look really good.

Unfortunately without your data I can't give you anything concrete, but hopefully this goes some way to helping :)

At the very least, ggplot2 is a very robust, very nice looking plotting tool, learning this will make your outputs look more impressive even if only on style alone!