# How to convert multiple binary columns into a single character column?

Tags: r

I would like to convert data frame df1 into data frame df2.

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
outcome_1 <- c(1,0,1)
outcome_2 <- c(1,1,0)
df1 <- data.frame(id,outcome_1,outcome_2)
```

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
outcome <- c("1,2","2","1")
df2 <- data.frame(id,outcome)
```

The answers to the following question almost do what I want, but in my case a row can have more than one positive outcome (e.g. first row needs to be "1,2"). Also, I would like the resulting column to be a character column.

[R: Converting multiple binary columns into one factor variable whose factors are binary column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421967/r-converting-multiple-binary-columns-into-one-factor-variable-whose-factors-are)

Please kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one more `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}'), .keep="unused") %>% 
  unite(outcome, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', ') %>% 
  mutate(outcome = gsub('outcome_', '', outcome))
```

```
  id outcome
1  1    1, 2
2  2       2
3  3       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Subset the `substring`s of the outcomes with their binary values coerced `as.logical`.

```
apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) toString(substring(names(df1)[-1], 9)[as.logical(x)]))
# [1] "1, 2" "2"    "1"
```

or

```
apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) paste(substring(names(df1)[-1], 9)[as.logical(x)], collapse=','))
# [1] "1,2" "2"   "1"
```

Using the first method:

```
cbind(df1[1], outcome=apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) toString(substring(names(df1)[-1], 9)[as.logical(x)])))
#   id outcome
# 1  1    1, 2
# 2  2       2
# 3  3       1
```

---

If you want a **nested list** you may use `list2DF`.

```
l <- list2DF(c(df1[1],
               outcome=list(apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) 
                                  as.numeric(substring(names(df1)[-1], 9))[as.logical(x)]))))
l
#   id outcome
# 1  1    1, 2
# 2  2       2
# 3  3       1
```

where

```
str(l)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ id     : num  1 2 3
# $ outcome:List of 3
# ..$ : num  1 2
# ..$ : num 2
# ..$ : num 1
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), outcome_1 = c(1, 0, 1), outcome_2 = c(1, 
1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: This is giving me an error message: Error: unexpected input in "cbind(df1[1], outcome=apply(df1[-1], 1, \"   It might be that I am missing something obvious as I am still relatively new to R.

Comment: @marc.th Oh, you are probably newer than your R version. Since R4.1 we can write shorthand `\(x)` for `function(x)`, so if you change that in the code and it will work. I recommend to always use the newest R, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr` and `purrr::pmap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  transmute(id, outcome = pmap(., ~ c(1*..2, 2*..3) %>% .[. != 0] %>% toString))

#>   id outcome
#> 1  1    1, 2
#> 2  2       2
#> 3  3       1
```

---

Or simply:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfr(df1, ~ data.frame(id = ..1, outcome = c(1*..2, 2*..3) %>% .[. != 0]
   %>% toString))

#>   id outcome
#> 1  1    1, 2
#> 2  2       2
#> 3  3       1
```

Answer (score 0):

How many `outcome_` columns are there? If just 2, this will work fine.

```
library(dplyr) 

df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    summarise(id = id, 
              outcome = paste(which(c(outcome_1,outcome_2)==1), collapse =",")) 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id outcome
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 1,2    
2     2 2      
3     3 1
```

If there are more than 2, try this:

```
df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    summarise(id=id, 
              outcome = paste(which(c_across(-id)== 1), collapse =","))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
outcome_col_idx <- grepl("outcome", colnames(df1))
cbind(
  df1[,!outcome_col_idx, drop = FALSE],
  outcome = apply(
    replace(df1, df1 == 0, NA)[,outcome_col_idx],
    1,
    function(x){
      as.factor(
        toString(
          gsub(
            "outcome_", 
            "", 
            names(x)[complete.cases(x)]
          )
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: `outcome_col_idx` is not defined in this solution